# How can I change the AWS Account Email with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, boto3, amazon-iam

Every AWS Account has an email associated to it. 
How can I change that email address for that account using boto3?

Comment: Not all AWS console activities can be done using Boto3.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to change an account's email address (Root) programmatically. You must log in to the console using Root credentials and update the email address.

Answer (score 0):

No as of Oct 2019 you can't update account information(including email) using boto or any other AWS provided SDKs.